# Anaconda and Torch7 Install Issue Mac 10.10

Tags: python, anaconda, torch

I had Anaconda installed prior to install Torch7.
I experienced no errors upon install Torch7 [using these instructions](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html#_).

I'm running OS 10.10.5

My .bash_profile is the following:

```
# added by Anaconda 2.3.0 installer 
export PATH="/Users/myusername/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="./Users/myusername/torch/install/bin/torch_activate:$PATH"
```

After I updating the .bash_profile I ran

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
$ th
```

And I get...

```
-bash: th: command not found
```

Any ideas? Should I remove Anaconda and try the installs again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`torch_activate` is not a directory. It should be sourced into your shell instead.

Try updating your `.bash_profile` to include

```
source /Users/myusername/torch/install/bin/torch-activate
```

Comment: David, thank you for helping out! Should I change my .bash_profile to remove the /torch_activate portion of the PATH?

Comment: David, thank you so much for your help! I got it to work.

Comment: David, the issue is that on OSx I found that it isn't underscore, it is a dash for `/torch-activate`.